# Spring Hibernate integration with maven and mysql

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to have a project with spring hibernate and mysql, the homepage works fine (it even gets data out from mysql and displays it) but when i click the add/edit or delete button i get a 404 error with the description **The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**
My student Controller.java

```
package com.joseph.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.joseph.model.Student;
import com.joseph.service.StudentService;

@Controller
public class StudentController {
@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map){
    Student student = new Student();
    map.put("student", student);
    map.put("studentList", studentService.getAllStudent());
    return "student";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/student.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result,   @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
//      System.out.println("inside doAction");
    Student studentResult = new Student();
//  System.out.println("after student object");
    switch(action.toLowerCase()){//only in Java7 you can put String in switch
    case "add":
        studentService.add(student);
        studentResult = student;
        System.out.println("Inside case action value is - add");
        break;
    case "edit":
        studentService.edit(student);
        studentResult = student;
        System.out.println("Inside case action value is - edit");
        break;
    case "delete":
        studentService.delete(student.getStudentId());
        studentResult = new Student();
        System.out.println("Inside case action value is - delete");
        break;
    case "search":
        Student searchedStudent = studentService.getStudent(student.getStudentId());
        studentResult = searchedStudent!=null ? searchedStudent : new Student();
        System.out.println("Inside case action value is - search");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("after switch");
    map.put("student", studentResult);
    map.put("studentList", studentService.getAllStudent());
    return "student";
}}
```

My web.xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>CRUDWebAppMavenized</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

My spring servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">



<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.joseph" />    


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

My spring1-servlet.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">



<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.joseph" />    


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

My student.jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Student Management</title>
   </head>
   <body>
          <h1>Students Data</h1>
 <form:form action="student.do" method="POST" commandName="student">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Student ID</td>
        <td><form:input path="studentId" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First name</td>
        <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last name</td>
        <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Year Level</td>
        <td><form:input path="yearLevel" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="action1" value="Add" />
            <input type="submit" name="action2" value="Edit" />
            <input type="submit" name="action3" value="Delete" />
            <input type="submit" name="action4" value="Search" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
         </form:form>
        <br>
           <table border="1">
       <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
         <th>Year level</th>
            <c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student">
                    <tr>
                    <td>${student.studentId}</td>
                    <td>${student.firstname}</td>
                 <td>${student.lastname}</td>
               <td>${student.yearLevel}</td>
     </tr>
        </c:forEach >
 </table>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Any help with this guys ?! I mean its able to connect to the database perectly fine i have no clue why the buttons are not working

Comment: Can you paste the view, in which you have edit button?

Comment: Zerocool sorry i forgot to post my student.jsp file here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see following two problems:

**First Issue:**

In your controller, you use

```
@RequestMapping(value="/student.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

but in your form you use

```
<form:form action="student.do" method="POST" commandName="student">
```

Shouldn't your form also use `/student.do`? Only reason I suspect this is because you have indicated that you get 404 (Page not found) error on trying to add/update.

**Second Issue:**

You use four submit buttons each with its own name

```
<input type="submit" name="action1" value="Add" />
<input type="submit" name="action2" value="Edit" />
<input type="submit" name="action3" value="Delete" />
<input type="submit" name="action4" value="Search" />
```

but, your controller method's @RequestParam assumes that you will get the value in one param.

```
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Student student,
      BindingResult result, 
      @RequestParam String action, //***THIS IS WRONG****
      Map<String, Object> map){
```

First you should change it have a name:

```
      @RequestParam("action") String action,
```

and, second add a hidden field (`<input type="hidden" name="action" />`) to carry the value of action to server and make sure that you update its value to "Add", "Edit", "Delete" or "Search" using Java Script by attaching on-click handlers to four action buttons.

**Third Possible Cause of Concern:**

Try to get rid of second dispatcher servlet, and use only one if possible.  So, make the default one handle `*.do` as [some people have faced issues when using two dispatcher servlet](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?10366-Multiple-dispatcher-servlets). I am sure it can be made to work but its difficult to pinpoint the error remotely using SO.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and, have all your `@RequestMapping` use `.do`, eg: `index.do` and `student.do`

This answer is based on what I can make out from the question.

Comment: I renamed all the buttons to action itself and i changed student.do in the display to /student.do , still getting Http 404 error cannot find the file /student.do ?

Comment: What is the URL that works?  The one for list page works so, can you share that URL along with the URL that does not work. I mean full URL starting with "http://...."

Comment: Added comment to use only one dispatcher servlet.  Found this link where people face similar issue: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?10366-Multiple-dispatcher-servlets but no clear answer

Comment: i have already tried ur 3rd suggestion, in that case nothing comes up at all ! so i keept the mapping at *.htm  my url is http://localhost:8080/CRUDWebAppMavenized/ for the host page  and http://localhost:8080/student.do when i click the edit button . and iam back to square 1 :(

Comment: I got the program ! Thanks there was an error in the jsp file :D